How to create a rdlc form (data set) for .netcore in visual studio. Is there any extensions in visual studio 2022?
Couldnt find dataset in (add new item) while creating the dataset for rdlc form in visual studio 2022, the project is in .NetCore.
Couldnt find any extension, that supports .netcore in visual studio 2022. Any solution,...

Hi Birindha, you can check this thread first, and following the steps to implement this feature.

And you may face some issue, you also can check this thread.
